# Wildfly activemq integration - messaging subsystem

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, activemq-classic, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am integrating activemq in wildfly and following [this guide](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToUseOutOfProcessActiveMQWithWildFly)

- If I define `resource-adapter` for `activemq standalone-full-ha.xml`,
  shall I leave messaging subsystem (default settings `hornetq`) as it is or do
  I need to remove messaging subsystem?
- If I remove messaging subsystem, what will be the value of `jms-connection-factory` under default-bindings of `ee` subsystem?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you're feeling venturous [WildFly 10 Beta2](http://wildfly.org/downloads/) uses activemq by default now.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, it is still in beta version. How can we configure activemq in wildfly 9(removing hornetq subsystem/ or keeping it)?

Comment: Yes it's still in Beta. I don't know how to configure activemq in 9. I'm not too familiar with messaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed messaging subsystem.

ConnectionFactory under resource-adapter subsystem becomes the default value of jms-connection-factory under ee subsystem.

For ex: jms-connection-factory="java:/ActiveMQ/QueueConnectionFactory"