# Problems with connecting WildFly and ActiveMQ "Classic" (WildFly 20 + ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.16.5 + Java 8)

Tags: wildfly, activemq-classic

I'm trying to configure ActiveMQ "Classic" (5.16.5) following this [guide](https://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-jms/integrate-activemq-with-wildfly/). I've also observed several topics from Stack Overflow:

- [Wildfly activemq integration - messaging subsystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187566/wildfly-activemq-integration-messaging-subsystem)
- [ActiveMQ lost messages if there is no commit pending on MDB with XA and RA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53762561/activemq-lost-messages-if-there-is-no-commit-pending-on-mdb-with-xa-and-ra)
- [Error: AMQ154003: Unable to connect to JMS ActiveMQ using Wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62230154/error-amq154003-unable-to-connect-to-jms-activemq-using-wildfly)

The problem is, when I'm trying to send a message to ActiveMQ "Classic" I get an exception:

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/AMQConnectionFactory
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:67)
```

Here are some key points from my `standalone-full.xml`:
MDB resource adapter is set:

```xml
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:7.0">
            ...
            <mdb>
                <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="activemq"/>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </mdb>
```

Default Artemis config is excluded:

```xml
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:10.0"/>
```

Resource adapter is configured (the RA was downloaded from a maven repository):

```xml
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:6.0">
            <resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter id="activemq">
                    <archive>
activemq-rar-5.16.5.rar
                    </archive>
                    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                    <config-property name="ServerUrl">tcp://localhost:61616?soTimeout=20000&amp;connectionTimeout=10000</config-property>
                    <config-property name="UserName">admin</config-property>
                    <config-property name="UseInboundSession">false</config-property>
                    <config-property name="Password">admin</config-property>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/AMQConnectionFactory" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="AMQConnectionFactory">
                            <xa-pool>
                                <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                                <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                                <prefill>false</prefill>
                                <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                            </xa-pool>
                            <timeout>
                                <blocking-timeout-millis>30000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                                <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
                            </timeout>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
                    <admin-objects>
                        <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/activemq/queue/ReceiveQueue" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ReceiveQueue">
                            <config-property name="PhysicalName">RCK.IN</config-property>
                        </admin-object>
                        <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/activemq/queue/ErrorQueue" pool-name="ErrorQueue">
                            <config-property name="PhysicalName">RCK.ERR</config-property>
                        </admin-object>
                        <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/activemq/queue/SendQueue" use-java-context="true" pool-name="SendQueue">
                            <config-property name="PhysicalName">RCK.OUT</config-property>
                        </admin-object>
                    </admin-objects>
                </resource-adapter>
            </resource-adapters>
        </subsystem>
```

Default connection factory is set in  section:
`jms-connection-factory="java:/AMQConnectionFactory"`

When all settings frome above are applied, I can see them in WF admin console.
And in the WF log also:

```
15:20:12,557 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "activemq-rar-5.16.5.rar" (runtime-name: "activemq-rar-5.16.5.rar")
...
15:20:13,838 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0006: Registered admin object at java:/activemq/queue/ErrorQueue
15:20:13,853 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0006: Registered admin object at java:/activemq/queue/SendQueue
15:20:13,853 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0006: Registered admin object at java:/activemq/queue/ReceiveQueue
...
15:20:13,857 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA AdminObject [java:/activemq/queue/ErrorQueue]
15:20:13,857 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA AdminObject [java:/activemq/queue/SendQueue]
15:20:13,857 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA AdminObject [java:/activemq/queue/ReceiveQueue]
15:20:13,857 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/AMQConnectionFactory]
...
15:20:14,259 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "activemq-rar-5.16.5.rar" (runtime-name : "activemq-rar-5.16.5.rar")
```

ActiveMQ 5.16.5 is running at the same host

```
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.16.5 (localhost, ID:<hostName>-59341-1681112999802-0:1) is starting
 INFO | Listening for connections at: tcp://<hostName>:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector openwire started
```

I've tried to change settings according to different manuals, but it didn't help. According to the pages I've gone through this configuration should work well. It seems that I've missed something in configuration, but I can't figure out what exactly.

**UPD1:**

> Is there any more to the stack-trace?

More of stacktrace:

```
17:33:43,628 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (Schedule-Transport-2-777) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection.
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory.java:210)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1322)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:499)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:632)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:604)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:440)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:67)
```

> Could you try to change your activemq resource adapter to activemq.rar ?

Do you mean in those places?

```xml
<mdb>
  <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="activemq"/>
  <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
</mdb>
```

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:6.0">
  <resource-adapters>
    <resource-adapter id="activemq">
...
```

Have not thought that it matters somehow.
But I may try, if there is any difference.

Comment: Is there any more to the stack-trace?

Comment: Could you try to change your activemq resource adapter to activemq.rar ?

Comment: @JustinBertram
Thanks for your answer. 
I've updated the question, see **UDP1:** section.

Comment: @ehsavoie Thanks for your answer. I've updated the question, see **UDP1:** section.

Comment: I think I was wrong on this

Comment: As an alternative: Use ActiveMQ without configuring the ConnectionFactory and without MDB: Provide ActiveMQ in Wildfly by just producing (\@Produce) the ActiveMQConnectionFactory and bootstrap listeners in \@Singleton
\@Startup beans which establishes the JMS Session in an \@PostConstruct init() method (works quite well for us)

Comment: The problem was with an extra ActiveMQ jar in the classpath, so I had two instances of the same class loaded by different classloaders.

The similar problem were discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987656/transport-scheme-not-recognized-tcp